# Combining ASP.NET webforms

Tags: asp.net

I have created 9 webforms in a project called "PIMS". I have not linked any form together simply because I dont know how to do that. Now when I load and run the application, it presents to me only the form that I have selected to run as "Start Page". How can I link all 9 webforms together present all the forms to users so they can choose the form they want to work on. Please suggest.

Kind regards,

Comment: You use links to connect the pages together.

Comment: Please "google" before asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can link any page or form by tag Anchor

```
<a href="form2.aspx">Click Here To Visit Form 2</a>
```

or any page

```
<a href="page2.html">Click Here To Visit Page 2</a>
```

or you can use ASP.NET Controls like HyperLink

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="form2.aspx">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
```

in advance you could use Javascript plugins to make menu with motions and good user experience
for example http://jqueryui.com/menu/

Comment: Thank you. I will try to implement it and if I have any question .. I will ask. Please do answer. Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

This is for winform only
First form is close and other form is open this way

```
  frmHome frm = new frmHome();
   frm.Show();
   this.Close();
```

frmHome is ur another from thats way u can open and close ur all forms.

Comment: For Webforms : u can use "response.redirect("secondpage.aspx");

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I am working with WebForms. I think winforms are different to webforms. But I appreciate your help. Thanks